# Creating and passing Type parameters in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, system.reflection

I have a method that takes an ApiController Type parameter as such:

```
private List<MethodInfo> GetMethods<T>()
{
  ...
}
```

I am trying to create a Type to pass to this method using the following:

```
  Type controller = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(
      type => type.Name.Contains(schema) && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ApiController))).First();

  var collection = GetMethods<controller>();
```

Well, "type or namespace controller could not be found..."
Driving me nuts!

I'm sure there is something easy I'm not seeing here, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think is what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx but this approach seems a little confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic type parameters have to be a type recognized by the compiler, not something created at runtime.  `controller` is a variable name, not a type the compiler can recognize at compile time, hence the error. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx

Comment: So, how do I create a instance of type ApiContoller from a generic Type type?

Comment: Here is how to get the constructor for a type:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h(v=vs.110).aspx    From there, you call `Invoke` on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ycw1y17(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can also use reflection to invoke methods on a type.  Here is an overview (can be messy at times):  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3a58006.aspx

Comment: Perhaps I haven't been clear enough. I have the name of my controller as a string. Call it "ContentController" I want to get and pass the Type <ContentController> of the controller to the method.

Comment: You can't use a generic type parameter unless it is known at compile time.  The only way I can think of is to pass it as a regular parameter of type `Type` and do away with the generic.

Comment: Yes, it seems this is true. I have other options obviously, but this was going to make things much easier. Thanks!